# Moving object from on ArrayList to Other

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have three lists, I need to move **Animal** object from list **animalSource** to list **animalTarget** using list **animalFilterName**. Only Animal with names present in the list **animalFilterName**, should be moved from  **animalSource**  to **animalTarget**, performance wise is there a better way of doing it than I am doing below. Using just sample data for now.

```
public class Animal {

    private String name;
    private String color;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}


public class MoveAnimal {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Animal> animalSource = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        List<String> animalFilterName = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Animal> animalTarget = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        animalFilterName.add("Name1");
        animalFilterName.add("Name2");

        Animal a1 = new Animal();
        a1.setColor("Color1");
        a1.setName("Name1");

        Animal a2 = new Animal();
        a2.setColor("Color2");
        a2.setName("Name2");

        Animal a3 = new Animal();
        a3.setColor("Color1");
        a3.setName("Name3");

        Animal a4 = new Animal();
        a4.setColor("Color1");
        a4.setName("Name4");

        Animal a5 = new Animal();
        a5.setColor("Color5");
        a5.setName("Name1");


        animalSource.add(a1);
        animalSource.add(a2);
        animalSource.add(a3);
        animalSource.add(a4);
        animalSource.add(a5);


        for(String s: animalFilterName) {
            for(Animal a: animalSource) {
                if(s.equals(a.getName())) {
                    animalTarget.add(a);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what was your question? EDIT: Ah, I missed it due to a missing "?".  What specifically do you mean by "better"? Faster, or cleaner-looking perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance, you would want to use Sets.  I'm pretty sure what you're doing is an O(m * n) operation for m = animalSource.size() and n = animalFilterName.size(), since lookups in ArrayLists are order n (to the lists size)

Lookups, inserts, and removals in Sets are generally either amortized constant time or logarithmic time (to the size of the set) (depending on the specifics of the set implementation) so worst case, using sets would reduce this to O(m * log(n)) for the same m and n.

```
Set<Animal> animalSource = ...;
Set<Animal> animalTarget = ...;
Set<String> animalFilterName = ...;

// add matching animals to new set
for (Animal a : animalSource)
    if (animalFilterName.contains(a.getName())) animalTarget.add(a);

// if you need to remove them from the first set, uncomment these lines
// for (Animal a : animalTarget)
//     animalSource.remove(a);
```

I think omitting line breaks in one line ifs and loops makes them look neater.  It's personal preference, you are not obliged to copy my style.

Edit: fixed time complexity

Another Edit: When you say move, do you mean add to one list and remove from the other?  Or do you just mean add to one list?

Third Edit: fixed fragmented line

Comment: Thanks Wug, Firstly I dont want to modify the original list, also I should have probably clarified that my 3 list data structures are fixed. I was thinking if its possible that I should transfer the value from list to map ..iterate over map and then add to another list? However, I like the way you have used for and if, instead of nested for. I am going to use that style for now. Please let me know if you have better solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm shown has complexity O(n x m) (due to the two nested loops) where n is the number of the elements in the first list and m is the number of elements in the filter.

To improve the algorithm for a better performance on bigger values of n and m, you can convert the filter list into a HashTable.

Like this:

```
 Hashtable<String, String> animalFilterName = new Hashtable<String, String>();
 animalFilterName.put("Name1", null);
 animalFilterName.put("Name2", null);
```

Then, the double for-loop can be simplified to:

```
for (Animal a: animalSource) {
    if (animalFilterName.containsKey(a.getName())) {
        animalTarget.add(a);
    }
}
```

Now complexity is much better: O(n) as hashtables behaves as an average of O(1). But you will only notice the difference with bigger numbers for n and m.

Comment: An "average of O(1)"? That seems to imply that some operations are faster than O(1) to offset those that are not.

Comment: Neat idea, but I'd use a HashSet straight away. Just a tad bit cleaner.

Comment: The good thing in this solution is if your filter is String based, otherwise it would be better to use a Set (maybe using HashSet implementation). By the way buen trabajo señor.

Comment: You are right Dave. It would be better it behaves most of the times as O(1) and only sometimes (if the key start to collides too much) it get worst. Thanks Luiggi.

Comment: Agree Jochen, sorry for that, my Java is a bit rusty, mainly working on C#.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind

1) rather than making a list of filters and iterating over it, you could make a set of filters and check if the animal's name is in the set.  This is better in big O terms, whether it's faster in real time depends on the actual collection sizes.

2) if you are neither sorting nor doing random access, LinkedLists are more efficient than ArrayLists.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Animal> animalSource = new LinkedList<Animal>();
    Set<String> animalFilterName = new HashSet<String>();
    List<Animal> animalTarget = new LinkedList<Animal>();

    //Set-up

    for (Animal a : animalSource) {
        if (animalFilterName.contains(a.getName())) {
            animalTarget.add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To respect the fact that you are allowing duplicate entries in your sourceAnimal list I would suggest the following:

Add two things:

An indexList of type List

```
List<List<Integer>>
```

that holds the indices of your animals in your sourceAnimal list. That means if you have the following sourceAnimal list

```
sourceAnimal: [ 0:"rabbit", 1:"dog", 2:"cat", 3:"horse", 4:"rabbit" ]
```

you would have the following (new) indexList:

```
indexList: [ 0: [0, 4], 1: [1], 2:[2], 3:[3] ]
```

This all makes sense when you add one last additional piece: a HashTable.

The HashTable maps an animal name to its corresponding index in the indexList where you can read the actual indices of all occurrences of that animal name inside the actual sourceAnimal list.

With that you would process your task as follows:

```
// Pseudo-Code !

foreach (animal: animalFilter) {

    if (hashtable.contains(animal) {

        int superIndex = hashtable.get(animal);

        foreach (int sourceAnimalIndex : indexList[superIndex]) {

            copy sourceAnimal[sourceAnimalIndex] to targetAnimal;
        }
    }

}
```

}

The **benefit** of this approach is that you avoid any iterations (except that over the indices of multiply accuring animals like in the example above index 0 and index 4 of the "rabbit" and the iteration over the animals you want to filter).

A **disadvantage** of course might be that you have to add additional data structures and add some maintaining overhead.

But I am sure if you are storing a high number of items in your sourceAnimalList the prevention of a 'master iteration' over the whole list for every animal will be quite efficient.